# Is my proof correct? (order of an element of a group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a finite group defined under an operation $*$. Then, given a member $a$ of the group, show that $\operatorname{ord}(a) = \operatorname{ord}(a^{-1})$. (i.e, $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have the same order)

So, my attempt was:

Say that $n$ is the order of $a$ and $m$ is the order of $a^{-1}$. So:
$$I = a * a * \cdots * a \quad n \quad \textrm{times}$$
And
$$I = a^{-1} * a^{-1} * \cdots * a^{-1} \quad m \quad \textrm{times}$$
So, we can write these two multiplication sequences as $a^n$ and $a^{-m}$.  Multiplying them, we get:
$$I * I = a^{n}*a^{-m}$$
And so
$$a^{n} * a^{-m} = I$$
This shows us that $a^{-m}$ is the inverse element of $a^{n}$. Since the inverse element of some $b$ is $b^{-1}$, then $(a^{n})^{-1} = a^{-n}$. And so:
$$a^{-n} = a^{-m}$$
And so it must be
$$ n = m $$

**My main question here is if the assumption that the inverse of $a^{n}$ is $a^{-n}$ in general. I'm not shure that it always holds.** Thanks in advance.

Comment: $aa^{-1} = e$  Suppose ${a^n}a^{-n} = e$ multiply on the left by $a$ and on the right by $a^{-1}$ and $a^{n+1} a^{-n-1} = aa^{-1} = e.$  So you are good there.  In your proof as written there is the possibility that $m$ is a multiple of $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a^{-n}=a^{-m}$ does not necessarily lead to $n=m$.

You may instead argue that if $n>m$, then $a^{n-m}=I$, contradicting the fact that $n$ is the order of $a$. Similar for the case $n<m$.

Only the case $n=m$ survives, which is the desired result.

**Edit**: $(a^n) ^{-1}=a^{-n}$ is in general true, since this is the definition of $a^{-n}$.

Comment: I don't understand why only the case $m=n$ will survive. Is it guaranteed that $a^0 = I$ always?

Comment: Yes that's why the case $m=n$ survives. The other two case dies because they will contradict the definition of **order**. Could you recall the definition?

Comment: Yes, i can see it, from the definition. But i didn't knew that $a^0 = I$ always.

Comment: Actually $a^0$ is an abuse of notation. We should not write $(a^n)(a^{-n})=a^{n-n}=a^0=I$. Instead, $(a^n)(a^{-n})=I$ since they are inverses of each other. Of course we can define $a^0=I$ and use it happily and this is also perfectly fine.